# how to connect sql server from vscode extension to java forms

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have been developing a simple java application that have a  form to enter data. I want to save the entered data into a database hosted my MySQL server (localhost) but i'm using mssql from an extension by vscode. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: you could follow the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I already followed that document but it do not specifically tell how to connect localhost mssql server to a java application

Comment: you could verify your connection in the lower status bar.refer to the [point 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15#connect-to-sql-server)